# Find how many strings in istringstream

Tags: c++, istringstream

I want to know how many strings there are in my variable when I use `istringstream`:

```
string cadena;
int num;

istringstream ss(cadena);
ss >> num;
int n = ss.size();  // This doesn't work
```

For example if `cadena` is: `"1 2 3 4"`, when I use `istringstream` I want to know how many strings are in `ss` (in this case 4).

Comment: Well, a `stringstream` isn't a `vector`...

Comment: which characters do you consider as terminating a string, only spaces?

Comment: I use istringstream because I don't want to count the spaces between the numbers.

Comment: You won't know without extracting them.

Comment: Why do you want this information?  If you need the numeric values, just using `std::istream_iterator<int>( ss )` in the initializer for `std::vector< int >` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The only way of which I'm aware is to parse the strings out to see. `std::distance` with an `istream_iterator` can do that for you:

```
std::distance(std::istream_iterator<string>(ss), 
              std::istream_iterator<string>());
```

Comment: After which, of course, he's read the stream, and has to create it again to reread it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yup -- though of course that's pretty easy to do with a stringstream. The obvious alternative would be to read the data into a vector, then find the size of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>

int  main()
{
  std::string str = ss.str();

  // int c = (int) std::count_if (str.begin(), str.end(), isspace) + 1;
  int c = 1;  // 0
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i <str.size(); i++ ) 
    if (isspace(str[i])) 
      c++;
  std::cout << c;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's because it's name is `std::count_if`.

Comment: But of course, that doesn't tell you anything about how many fields there might be.

Comment: Still doesn't recognise this fuction.

Comment: The idea was to do it without loops,but i guees it's impossible,thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like, add while loop

`while(ss>>cadena) {`